# how to randomly initialize particles system in different places of scene in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently tried asking this question but I realized it was not a sufficient question. In my game the player is a fire fighter learner and i want to broke out fire randomly in my game (like not predictable by player), but i did not know how to implement this.
So far i have done this but nothing goes good.(I have a empty object called t in unity which have 3 to 5 particles systems, and all are set to dont awake at start) 
code is here :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Example : MonoBehaviour {
public ParticleSystem[] particles;
public int numOn = 3;
public int j;

void Start() {
    for (int i = 0; i < particles.Length - 1; i++) {
         j = Random.Range(i + 1, particles.Length - 1);
        ParticleSystem t = particles[j];
        particles[j] = particles[i];
        particles[i] = t;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < numOn; j++ )
    {
        particles[j].Play();
    }
        }
        }
```

help will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using prefabs. Create a game object in the editor that has any particle systems and scripts your fire objects need. Once it's good, drag the object from the hierarchy into your project. This will create a prefab (you can now remove it from the scene).  Now, on your spawning script, add a field of type GameObject and drag the prefab you made before into it. Now, when you need to create one, just call `Instantiate(prefabVar)` to create a copy of your prefab.

Edit:
For your specific case, since you only want one fire to be instantiated in a random location, you could have your spawning script look something like this:

```
public Transform[] SpawnPoints;
public GameObject FirePrefab;

void Start() {
    Transform selectedSpawnPoint = SpawnPoints[(int)Random.Range(0, SpawnPoints.Count - 1)];
    Instantiate(FirePrefab, selectedSpawnPoint.position, selectedSpawnPoint.rotation);
}
```

This solution would allow for you to potentially spawn more than one fire object if you needed.  An alternative would be if you will only ever have exactly one fire object in the scene at all.  Instead of instantiating from a prefab, the object is already in the scene and you just move it to one of your spawn points at the start of the scene.  An example script on the fire object itself:

```
public Transform[] SpawnPoints;

void Start() {
    Transform selectedSpawnPoint = SpawnPoints[(int)Random.Range(0, SpawnPoints.Count - 1)];
    transform.position = selectedSpawnPoint.position;
    transform.rotation = selectedSpawnPoint.rotation;
}
```

Comment: i m going good till above these line:
"Now, when you need to create one, just call Instantiate(prefabVar) to create a copy of your prefab."
but how could i do it randomly in a scene.
1st of all we have to place these prefab on a specific location in our scene before deletion. 
2ndly how could we do it on random location whenever that level loads or restarted.

Comment: @FarhanAli I don't know what you mean by that comment

Comment: e.g if i want to place fire prefab in a shop and next time when i load that level or restart that level then it should(fire) be on any other place in the scene.